# pass parameter in table valued function using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I have created a table valued return function which returns me a table . here is call of my function as follow

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[StateFixedTaxesCalculation](3020,16,1,1006)
```

and its working OK for me , now i want to use this function call in a select statment , so i can pass `16` which is basically `employeeId` dynamically.

So i have decided to use inner join with table returned by that function . Like this

```
SELECT * FROM Employee as E
INNER JOIN  dbo.[StateFixedTaxesCalculation](3020,16,1,1006) as TC   ON TC.EmployeeId=E.EmployeeId
```

but now how can i pass `16` as dynamic value of all `employeeId` one by one .

Answer (score 67, accepted):

use [`outer/cross apply`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select *
from Employee as E
    cross apply dbo.[StateFixedTaxesCalculation](3020, E.EmployeeId, 1, 1006) as TC
```

if you still have to filter by `TC.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId`, you can do this with subquery:

```
select *
from Employee as E
    cross apply (
        select TT.*
        from dbo.[StateFixedTaxesCalculation](3020, E.EmployeeId, 1, 1006) as TT
        where TT.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
    ) as TC
```

Comment: Thanks its works for me . I have some few more difficulties but i post them as a separate question .

Comment: After searching for hours (mostly on wrong keywords may be), I came to this question. It saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Great job on this one, I don't get to use cross apply too often, so I always have to go look it up :)